# I consider him irresponsible VS I consider him to be irresponsible

Tags: grammar, phrase-choice

Which prase is correct?

- I consider him irresponsible
- I consider him to be irresponsible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"to be" is optional here but leaving it in makes the statement clearer.

Here, "to be" is used as a linking verb connecting the noun "him" to the adjective "irresponsible".

From [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/linking-verbs/):

> Linking verbs are verbs that serve as a connection between a subject and further information about that subject. They do not show any action; rather, they “link” the subject with the rest of the sentence. The verb **to be** is the most common linking verb, but there are many others, including all the sense verbs.